# Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager is undefined error in IE11, working fine in IE10 and below

Tags: javascript, asp.net, .net, internet-explorer

My clients have updated their browser to IE11 from IE10.
I am getting below error on page refresh
Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager is undefined.

Please check my code

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="scmMain" EnableCdn="false" runat="server" AsyncPostBackTimeout="0"
    ScriptMode="Release">
   </asp:ScriptManager>

<script type="text/javascript">
    Sys.Application.add_init(function () {
        Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_beginRequest(ieAjaxPageLoaded);
        Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_pageLoaded(ieAjaxPageLoaded);
        Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_endRequest(ieAjaxEndRequest);
        Sys.Application.add_load(NeoSpin_PageLoad);
    });

    function header_onclick() {
    }
    function End(sender, args) { }
</script>
```

This works fine on IE10 and below

I have already tried below links - but no help -

['Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager' is null or not an object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7062286/sys-webforms-pagerequestmanager-is-null-or-not-an-object)

[Microsoft JScript runtime error: 'Sys' is undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1931701/microsoft-jscript-runtime-error-sys-is-undefined)

http://encosia.com/updated-your-webconfig-but-sys-is-still-undefined/

http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/543002/Unableplustoplusgetpluspropertyplus-27PageRequestM

Thanks
Fahad Mullaji

Comment: What version of .NET and ASP.NET are you using? Are you sure that those three JavaScript functions are defined? I just copy pasted your code into a new WebForms project in VS2013 and couldn't reproduce any errors in IE11 once I defined `ieAjaxPageLoad`, `ieAjaxEndRequest`, and `NeoSpin_PageLoad`.

Comment: I am using v4.0.30319 of .NET. And even if i define those function its not working. The problem is PageRequestManger is only not defined. I don't understand why its not working. It worked for you right?

Comment: Yes, no JavaScript errors at all for me and I was able to watch the page run through some of the `PageRequestManager` events by adding `console.log` statements in those callback functions. If you view source on your page and find the MsAjax.js reference, can you load that src in a browser? Can the users having trouble? Also, this might sound odd, but ensure that the time and timezone are set correctly on your server if you have control of that. That can cause 404 errors on ScriptResource.axd and WebResource.axd resources.

Answer (score 2):

So I don't have a solution for you, but here is what I think is going on based on my experience with my Server compared to my local development machine. It looks like you are using the ASP.NET control toolkit, which was sort of deprecated a few years back and should be available as an open source project on Codeplex now. It is primarily driven from the server-side and I am betting it is doing some poor browser sniffing since that was a common thing to do back then. What it should do is feature detection.

So where does the problem come from? So my local dev machine reports IE 11 as majorVersion == 11. My server reports majorVersion as 7. So there really needs to be a patch to fix the server, but I am not sure if it exists yet. The other option is to go patch the control toolkit to NOT browser sniff and feature detect instead. That is a very daunting task to say the least.

Just 2 cents worth on the topic though. This is a real concern because I am guessing this issue might actually keep your company or client from actually updating their systems, which eventually will catch up to them and cause them major issues, like not upgrading XP machines by April is going to cause a lot of companies.

Sorry I do not have a solution for you, but this is very interesting as I am doing research on issues that need to be resolved to help companies get off obsolete platforms like old IE & XP right now.

Comment: Huh!! How to change majorVersion? Will that solve the problem?

Comment: not something you can actually change. It is read by parsing the user agent string and matching it against the browser caps file which the asp.net team sort of maintains. I say sort of because it was not a problem for them 10 years ago as there were not that many browsers. Today there are thousands. The file is not updated frequently enough to keep up.

Comment: BTW can you confirm you are using the ASP.NET AJAX control toolkit, because that is what it looks like to me. http://ajaxcontroltoolkit.codeplex.com/ That is where you can get the latest code. Maybe the guys managing the project now have fixed code to not sniff, but feature detect, which would solve the issue. I honestly do not know since I stopped following the code several years ago.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is with the userAgent string sent by IE 11 where Dot Net 4.0 frameworks or below do not recognize as Internet Explorer.
You can fix this problem either by upgrading your server to Dot Net 4.5 or
you can add add an ie.Browser file in your web application within the folder App_Browsers with the following entry

```
<browser id="InternetExplorer" parentID="Mozilla">
    <identification>
        <userAgent match="Trident/(?'layoutVersion'[7-9]|0*[1-9]\d+)(\.\d+)?;(.*;)?\s*rv:(?'version'(?'major'\d+)(\.(?'minor'\d+)))" />
        <userAgent nonMatch="IEMobile" />
        <userAgent nonMatch="MSIE " />
    </identification>

    <capabilities>
        <capability name="browser"              value="InternetExplorer" />
        <capability name="version"              value="${version}" />
        <capability name="majorversion"         value="${major}" />
        <capability name="minorversion"         value="${minor}" />
        <capability name="layoutEngine"         value="Trident" />
        <capability name="layoutEngineVersion"  value="${layoutVersion}" />
        <capability name="type"                 value="InternetExplorer${major}" />
    </capabilities>
</browser>
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be an known issues as the framework is not able to detect IE 11 as Microsoft Internet Explorer. You can download the patch from following link to resolve the problem.

[Click here to Download patch from Microsoft site](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2836939/en-us)

```
Or following:

<head>
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=10" />
</head>
```

Comment: Ok thanks i will try this and let you know if it worked out for me or not. And one more thing is it advisable to install this patch in production environment?

Comment: I am using v4.0.30319

Comment: To confirm that this behaviour is because of IE 11 only try to enter following code:<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=10" /> in your page and then try again whether problem solves or not.

Comment: I did this but still the problem was there. But application works just fine in IE 10 browser.

Answer (score 0):

Finally found solution to this problem. I upgraded .NET version from 4.0 to 4.5.
I don't know how it internally works.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

the references config file from Liran will work but only if Mozilla has javascript enabled. .Net 4.0 didn't have javascript enabled for Mozilla. This is from the default.browser file from a server with .Net 4.5:

```
<browser id="Mozilla" parentID="Default">
    <identification>
        <userAgent match="Mozilla" />
    </identification>
    <capture>
    </capture>
    <capabilities>
        <capability name="javascript" value="true" />
```

- then run aspnet_regbrowsers.exe because browser files don't actually do anything until you run that.
- If you're using a App_Browsers folder in your project you'll also need to delete your temporary internet files (mine was in C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files but your results may vary of course). You have to delete it because ASPNet needs to regenerate a dynamic DLL it generates from your App_Browsers/*.browser files.

Of course the easiest way is just install .Net 4.5. This answer is only applicable to people who can't for some reason.